# Cannot access a login site for a wifi with no password [20.04]

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

Im on vacation stayed 2 days in 1 room and moved to another one in the same hotel it worked when i was there and wont anymore
Other devices do connect and work also and show the login prompt, the laptop im using shows as connected but doesnt put the prompt to login up on a web browser
I tried configuring dns, i already tried restarting network manager and i removed the hotel wifi in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/the wifi name.nmconnection
Dhclient gives no outout

> https://bap.aws.opennetworkexchange.net/cn3k/loginapi.jsp?UI=03511c&NI=0050e803511c&UIP=50.236.196.74&MA=30C9AB98D05F&RN=1400&PORT=1400&RAD=yes&PP=no&PMS=no&SIP=172.20.1.208&OS=https://172.20.1.208&2F

But when put in to firefox it says it is having trouble finding the site
I tried other devices (my phone) and it came up as a

> secure.guestinternet.com and doubletree.hiltonwifi.com

Any help?

Comment: You want the Hotel's "captive" portal to automatically popup and prompt you to enter the password. Try deleting your browser cookies and also remove the browser's saved passwords/logins. Then, when you select the hotel's Wi-Fi in Ubuntu, if the browser doesn't automatically pop up, just open your browser and try to go to a random website (like askubuntu.com); at that point you should be prompted for the room's Wi-Fi password.

Comment: I followed these steps but they didnt seem to work, what i did so far is go to my web browser, delete cookies, browsing history, and saved logins and passwords, i forgot the network and restarted my network manager, conndcted it didnt open a prompt so i went to an example site and still didnt prompt me, i waited for it to load, and it didmt ask for a prompt and timed out